# Derivatives of $G_h(u):=\int_0^{2\pi} h(\cos t)h(\cos(t - \arccos(u)))dt$ when $h$ is positive-homogeneous

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, integration, integral-transforms, differential-calculus

Let $h:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous which is positive-homogeneous of order $p \ge 1$, and define $G_h:[-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ by
$$
G_h(u):=\int_0^{2\pi} h(\cos t)h(\cos(t - \arccos(u)))dt.
$$

> **Question.** *If $h$ is continuously differentiable (almost-everywhere), is there any functional relationship between $G_{h'}$ and $G_h$ ?*

I am thinking of something of the form $G_{h'}(u) = f_p((G_h)'(u))$ for some function $f_p:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (peprhaps a linear function like $f_p(z) = (p-1)z$ ?).

### Examples

Consider $h(x) := x^3$, a $\mathcal C^\infty$ positive-homogeneous function of order $p=3$. One computes
$$
\begin{split}
G_h(u) &= \int_0^{2\pi}\cos(t)^3\cos(t-\arccos(u)))^3dt =  \frac{\pi u(2u^2+3)}{8}\\
G_{h'}(u) &= G_{x \mapsto 3x^2}(u) = 3\int_0^{2\pi}\cos (t)^2 \cos(t-\arccos(u))^2dt = \frac{3\pi(2u^2+1)}{4}\\
&= 2(G_h)'(u)  = (p-1)(G_h)'(u).
\end{split}
$$